# Android: How to kill the current activity if the new activity is the same with the current one?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I know it's kinda hard to understand the question, I'm new to Android, what I mean is that:

say I have an activity A that is currently active, then I put device sleep and wake up the device, activity A still active right now.

At this time a dialog will pop up and I press "Yes", a new activity A will be created. What I concerned is that, how do I kill the old A and then create the new A?

Right now when I click "Yes" the new A is created but it's not showing correctly.

Comment: Why you want a work around instead of trying to find the problme -> `Right now when I click "Yes" the new A is created but it's not showing correctly.`? and what does `not showing correctly` mean?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? What's wrong with the Activity A that's already there?

Comment: @Karakuri it happens when user do nothing and the device will sleep automatically later. And when user wake up the device, the content on fragment should be refreshed.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it's not showing correctly because the fragment is not recreated which is caused by I wake up the device and I stay on this fragment.

Comment: @Zip That's fine, you don't need to kill the activity and show a new one, you just need to update the UI. You can use the lifecycle callbacks to do that, like `onStart()` (either in the Activity or the Fragment)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are trying to achieve, but this code snippet should do what you want.

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

A different alternative is calling

```
recreate();
```

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate) says: This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it."

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourclass.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
```